# FileNotFoundException on linux machine when using getClassLoader().getResource

Tags: java, linux

I made already quite some research on internet for this problem. I had no luck so far. Basically this piece of code works fine on Windows with my Junit test src\test\java\com\project\utils\MyTestCase.java :

```
URL urlApplicationContext = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("applicationContext.xml");
final String[] paths = { urlApplicationContext.getFile()};
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(paths);
```

This file is located  there:

\src\test\resources\applicationContext.xml

However on the Jenkins machine which run on linux I got the following error :

> testSimple(com.project.ClientImplTest): IOException parsing XML
>   document from file
>   [/data/continuous/workspace/sonar/main_proj/data/continuous/workspace/sonar/main_proj/target/main/WEB-INF/test-classes/applicationContext.xml];
>   nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   data/continuous/workspace/sonar/main_proj/target/main/WEB-INF/test-classes/applicationContext.xml
>   (No such file or directory)

I already verified that the file /data/continuous/workspace/sonar/main_proj/target/main/WEB-INF/test-classes/applicationContext.xml does exist.

Why the getResource() does not find the correct path on Linux. It seems it finds data/continous/... instead of /data/continous/... for some reason ? Therefore  FileSystemXmlApplicationContext may return an exception because it cannot find the file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some debug output. URL has nice `toString()` method. Thus you'll get where app is looking for file.

It looks like you missed slash at the very beginning. Replace `data/continuous/...` to `/data/continuous/...` in your resource loader.

Comment: Hi, What the method to load ressource is this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("applicationContext-hibernate-junit.xml") . The path on linux machine is retrieved dynamically . I don't know what you mean by "resource loader" ?

Comment: `getResource` only gives you an url. Then you load xml by url and get exception because slash is missed => path is incorrect. The method where you load this xml I called resource loader. If this method is inside Jenkins, then possibly you're using it wrong.

Comment: try: 1)System.out.println(urlApplicationContext); 2) ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("target/main/WEB-INF/test-classes/applicationContext.xml");

Comment: Thank you Sergey. This line of code ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("target/main/WEB-INF/test-classes/applicationCon‌​text.xml"); fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in my project - it was caused by spaces in the path - to handle such cases, you need to use the URL's **toURI()** method - do following:

```
ApplicationContext ctx;
URL urlApplicationContext = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("applicationContext.xml");
if (urlApplicationContext != null) {
    File appCtxFile = new File(urlApplicationContext.toURI());
    ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{ appCtxFile.getAbsolutePath() });
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find XML file 'applicationContext.xml'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have enough rep to upvote or comment or anything I will say what I need to say here lol

Oifan is absolutely right (read answer needs accepting).

Had the same issue on Jenkins. Code was trying to access a file during a test, path had spaces in it, resulted in `FileNotFoundException`. The file was definitely in the right location.

My testing also showed that the spaces were the culprit. We were just going to rename the project in Jenkins which would have resulted in no more spaces in our directory structure. Then I came across Oifan's answer.

Converting the `URL` from `getResource()` to a `URI` and passing that to `File()` solved the problem for us too.

BTW, the problem is not isolated to linux. I have seen this behavior on Windows Jenkins slaves as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Jenkins does not complain about the `applicationContext.xml` file, but this one: `data/continuous/workspace/sonar/main_proj/target/main/WEB-INF/test-classes/applicationContext-hibernate-junit.xml`

Comment: There was a bad copy paste in the original post. Jenkins complains about applicationContext.xml. I modified the post.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the getResource() does not find the correct path on Linux.

I think you need to look at your code and stacktraces again.

The `getResource()` method does not throw `IOException`, or any subclasses of `IOException`.  Not ever.

The exception you are seeing is being thrown by ... something else.  And it is pretty clear from the message that the code that throws that exception is not *looking* for a file called "applicationContext.xml" either.

**UPDATE**

Even following your correction, it remains an incontravertable fact that `getResource()` cannot cause a `FileNotFoundException`.  You are looking at the wrong code.